# AnalysisException: 'write' can not be called on streaming Dataset/DataFrame

Tags: python, databricks

I am trying to save the streaming dataframe as silver delta table in databricks. However, I encounter this error: *AnalysisException: 'write' can not be called on streaming Dataset/DataFrame*

This is the dataframe I am trying to save as table:

```
df_streaming = spark.sql(SQL_TELEMETRY_JOB).coalesce(1)
```

This is my line of code:

```
df_streaming.write.mode("append").format("delta").saveAsTable(silver.telemetry_job2)
```

Any tips on how to solve this one? I am new to databricks and DBFS.

Comment: Well, it is as it says, you can't write a streaming table. What is the value of `SQL_TELEMETRY_JOB`?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, your DataFrame is a *streaming dataframe* and `.write` is not supported on streaming dataframes.

Instead, you must use `.writeStream` to define your streaming *sink* like so:

```scala
df_streaming
  .writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .outputMode("append")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "dbfs:/checkpoint/location/")
  .toTable(silver.telemetry_job2)
```

https://docs.databricks.com/en/structured-streaming/delta-lake.html